# Event price to have a membership discount when events are unaware of membership

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have a bit of a design pattern issue. Say I have a module called "Events" which has the following class:

```
public class Event {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }
}
```

Now say I have another module called "Membership" which has a dependency on this module. This is a basic membership module where if someone subscribes to a membership they will receive a discount on the cost of the events.

The problem I have is how do I get the correct event cost in the Events module taking into account the discount when the Events module has no knowledge of the Membership module.

One idea I have come up with is to add a service in the Events module, e.g.:

```
public interface IEventCost {
    decimal GetCost(Event @event);
}
```

Then I would implement this in the Membership module. However every time I display the event's cost I would then have to inject the service and call the GetCost method passing in the event. I'm not sure I like this idea and I was wondering if there was a design pattern to handle this scenario.

I'd really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're on the right track with adding an interface to the Events module. I would name the interface `Discount`, since that is the domain concept you need to create. `Membership` should implement `Discount`. This relationship is consistent with the desired direction of dependency from Memberships to Events.

In terms of an actual design pattern, I am reminded of the `Decorator` example from Head First Design Patterns, where condiments compose beverages. To apply the metaphor here: Events are the beverages and Memberships are the condiments.

Here is some Java/pseudocode of how it might be implemented.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        Event goldenFoo = new GoldMembership(new FooEvent());
        System.out.println(goldenFoo.eventCost());
    }
    interface Event {
        String eventName();
        double eventCost();
    }
    interface Discount extends Event {
        default double discountValue() { return 0.0; }
        default double discountPercent() { return 0.0; }
    }
    interface Membership extends Discount {
        String membershipName();
    }
    static class FooEvent implements Event {
        @Override public String eventName() { return "FOO"; }
        @Override public double eventCost() { return 100; }
    }
    static class GoldMembership implements Membership {
        private final Event event;
        GoldMembership(Event event) {
            this.event = event;
        }
        @Override public String eventName() { return event.eventName(); }
        @Override public double eventCost() { return event.eventCost() - event.eventCost() * discountPercent(); }
        @Override public String membershipName() { return "GOLD"; }
        @Override public double discountPercent() { return 0.30; }
    }
}
```

Of course you can split up these classes into multiple modules. The design offers a lot of flexibility to extend in three different directions: `Event`, `Discount`, `Membership`, and to compose the domain models in different ways.

Comment: I read the above code like Discount `IS` Event, Membership `IS` Discount... To me, discount is not an event, its a rule to calculate the final price for a user.

Comment: Also, to construct `Membership` you need an event which looks strange from domain point of view.

Comment: Don't get hung up on the names. `Discount` is just a decorator interface. If you'd like to call it `DiscountedEvent` or `DiscountedEventWrapper` that's fine too. The question is tagged `design-patterns`. I recommend looking up the `Decorator` pattern, particularly the example from Head First Design Patterns. I think you'll find the structure of this code is remarkably similar to the example in the book.

Comment: Thanks, I've been reading up on the Decorator pattern and this looks like the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I'd look at introducing `EventRegistration` entity into the equation. Event itself has only base price, but the registration is something that people actually pay for.

To construct `EventRegistration`, you will need an Event and User (who may have membership)

I'd also introduce a `EventDiscount` entity as well, as its a separate domain concept.  And finally, `EventRegistrationPricingService` will be responsible for getting the final price for the registration and know about all discounts (regardless of the module where they are implemented).

Something like:

```
public interface IEventRegistrationDiscount(){

   <MoneyType> GetDiscountedPrice(EventRegistration registration);
   bool IsApplicable(EventRegistration registration);
}

public class MembershipDiscount: IEventRegistrationDiscount {

    public MembershipDiscount(int percentage){
        this.percentage = percentage;
    }

    public bool IsApplicable(EventRegistration registration){
        return registration.User.HasMembership;
    }

    public <MoneyType> GetDiscountedPrice(EventRegistration registration) {
        if (IsApplicable(registration)){
            //your real discounting logic here
            return new MoneyType(registration.Event.Cost*(100-percentage)/100);
        }
    }
}

public class EventRegistrationPricingService
{
  private IEnumerable<IEventDiscount> discounts;

  public EventDiscountService(IEnumerable<IEventDiscount> discounts){

      this.discounts = discounts;
  }

  public <MoneyType> GetPrice(EventRegistration registration){
      var applicableDiscounts = discounts.Select(x => x.IsApplicable(registration));
      var bestDiscount = applicableDiscounts.FirstOrDefault(); 


// if you got many possible discounts then you need to figure out what is the "best" one
          //there could be more logic than just discounts
          return bestDiscount != null ? bestDiscount.GetDiscountedPrice(registration) : registration.Event.Cost;
      }
    }
```

Note: `MoneyType` is a type that you use for money. It should be a special type that will know how to deal with rounding at least. There are a few examples of those on the web.